# How to timeout or skip any matcher(Regular Expression) in java if taking too long time to match?

Tags: java, regex

In my project I'm using regex to match with string. Here String is dynamic so sometime it takes too long time to match string.
here is my code (`Keywords.p_resumeHeading` is pattern object):

```
for (int k = 0; k < forcheck.length; k++) {
    Matcher m = Keywords.p_resumeHeading.matcher(forcheck[k].trim());
    if (m.find()) {

        //System.out.println("Resume heading hai ");
        finalresult = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your regex? Maybe there is a way to improve its performance? Maybe you are facing [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)?

Comment: I agree, when a regex takes too long to match, you should look at the regex first, not the code that applies the regex.

Comment: actually my regex is quite long :                                                                       static String resumeHeadingRegex = "^[\\s\\W]*(CURRICULUM VITA|RESUME|CURRICULUM VITAE|CURRICULUM VITAE|CV|C V)+([\\s]*[^a-zA-Z]*)*$";                                                                                                       and the the string is dynamic.

Comment: I improve allot but now my tool is going to deployed so  in future if same problem will occur  than my application can hang . that's  why I'm looking for any solution to match till a limited time duration .

Answer (score 1):

I've got a similar case with a 'malformed' regex. The best way to deal with it is to limit repetition of your groups with {x} where x is a realistic number (5 or 10) maybe will suffice. Check http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html on limiting repetition.

Whitout your regex, I can't help you better.

Comment: actually my regex is quite long :                                                                       static String resumeHeadingRegex = "^[\\s\\W]*(CURRICULUM VITA|RESUME|CURRICULUM VITAE|CURRICULUM VITAE|CV|C V)+([\\s]*[^a-zA-Z]*)*$";                                                                                                       and the the string is dynamic.

Comment: A construct like this ()* can cause a StackOverflow or a catastrophic backtracking. Replace it with {10} and check if you have the same results: "^[\\s\\W]*(CURRICULUM VITA|RESUME|CURRICULUM VITAE|CURRICULUM VITAE|CV|C V)+([\\s]*[^a-zA-Z]*){10}$"

Comment: Thanks @JFPicard , It's working very well . thanks for help .

Answer (score 0):

You could consider to submit a Runnable to an [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to start the find operation in another thread and use the returned [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) object to specify the maximum time to wait.

You can use the [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class to create an ExecutorService.